# How do I install a library via vcpkg from a network shared folder?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, vcpkg

Lets say I have a shared folder on local network server where I've placed some library sources (e. g. szip).

And I need to install that library via **vcpkg**.

I've tried to change portfile.cmake to the following:

```
vcpkg_download_distfile(ARCHIVE
    URLS "\\\\127.0.0.1\\vcpkg_packages\\szip-2.1.1.tar.gz"
    FILENAME "szip-2.1.1.tar.gz"
    SHA512 ada6406efb096cd8a2daf8f9217fe9111a96dcae87e29d1c31f58ddd2ad2aa7bac03f23c7205dc9360f3b62d259461759330c7189ef0c2fe559704b1ea9d40dd
)
```

But I'm getting **Failed. Status : 6, "Couldn't resolve host name"** error:
[image]

So how to specify network shared folder correctly (I'm on Windows 10 x64 1903)?

Comment: Use symbolic link ( mapped the shared folder) to fool vcpkg into believing that the library is located in the default installed directory.

Comment: I suspect that UNC path is not a URL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like

`file://127.0.0.1/vcpkg_packages/szip-2.1.1.tar.gz`

or set the env variable `VCPKG_DOWNLOADS` to a folder containing all the downloaded libraries